# List file information in a text file for all the files in a directory

Tags: r

I am trying to list all the information in a text file related to the files in a directory. I used the statement below to do this:

```
file.info(list.files(path="C:\\temp\\dat\\work",pattern="\\.T$))
```

The output I got was-

```
          size isdir mode mtime ctime atime  exe
17517.T   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
17530.T   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
17565.T   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

All I want is to get all the information in a text file in the format below-

```
Date modified  Time modified         size   file name
10/08/2015      02:39 AM            122055    17517.T
10/08/2015      02:39 AM            122662    17530.T
10/01/2015      08:37 PM             76613    17565.T
```

Comment: What does `file.info("C:\\temp\\dat\\work")` give?

Comment: size isdir mode               mtime
C:\\temp\\dat\\work    0  TRUE  777 2015-10-08 10:48:56
                                         ctime               atime exe
C:\\temp\\dat\\work 2015-02-07 15:15:47 2015-10-08 10:48:56  no

Comment: @seth please see above

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to tell `list.files` to return full paths. Without it I can duplicate your behaviour:

```
> file.info(list.files(path="/home/rowlings/bin",pattern=".sh$"))
                   size isdir mode mtime ctime atime uid gid uname grname
backupStatus.sh      NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA  NA  <NA>   <NA>
checkFetchmail.sh    NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA  NA  <NA>   <NA>
postgresBackup.sh    NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA  NA  <NA>   <NA>
postgresBackup2.sh   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA  NA  <NA>   <NA>
roxbuild.sh          NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA  NA  <NA>   <NA>
```

What happens is that `list.files`  returns just the file name, so then `file.info` is looking in the working directory, not finding the files, and returning `NA` everywhere.

With `full.names=TRUE` then `list.files` returns the full path, so `file.info` *can* find the files and report back okay:

```
> file.info(list.files(path="/home/rowlings/bin",pattern=".sh$", full.names=TRUE))
                                      size isdir mode               mtime
/home/rowlings/bin/backupStatus.sh    1333 FALSE  755 2013-06-03 14:24:47
/home/rowlings/bin/checkFetchmail.sh   427 FALSE  755 2009-01-17 22:18:40
/home/rowlings/bin/postgresBackup.sh    98 FALSE  755 2008-09-11 16:27:55
/home/rowlings/bin/postgresBackup2.sh  206 FALSE  755 2009-09-09 16:27:10
/home/rowlings/bin/roxbuild.sh         850 FALSE  755 2011-03-08 10:11:06
```

Comment: @ Spacedman-Thank you very much! It worked. I just have one more question. I have a list of files along with the path name. I want to extract the file name of each file. How can this be done? I tried using basename() but it did not work out.

Comment: @asmi you should click the "tick" next to this answer to accept it as the best answer and ask your other question as a completely new question - the answer may already be out there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#get file list - your list of files would be different
fileList <- list.files()[1:5]

#result
cbind(
  file.info(fileList)[,c("size"), drop=FALSE],
  x = as.character(file.mtime(fileList))) %>% 
  separate(x,
           into = c("DateModified","TimeModified"),
           sep=" ") %>% 
  add_rownames %>% 
  select(DateModified,
         TimeModified,
         Size=size,
         FileName=rowname)

#output will be something similar to below
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# 
#   DateModified TimeModified  Size     FileName
#          (chr)        (chr) (dbl)        (chr)
# 1   2015-09-07     11:59:31   748     data.txt
# 2   2015-07-20     13:02:31   199    ddata.csv
# 3   2015-08-17     09:59:13   402  desktop.ini
# 4   2015-06-25     11:20:02 18432 Drawing2.vsd
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the vignette example here 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/file.info.html

```
ncol(finf <- file.info(dir()))
 finf
```

**EDIT**

Try to change  the directory path to other other folders and see if you were able to reproduce the anticipated results on other files ( may be a .R ) . It works for me without NA. What kind of files you are dealing with ? Check the properties of the files.

I replicated you answer as well. When you are working in one directory lets say current working directory is `getwd()` c:\temp and attempting to call a folder in c:\temp\folders\data in other directory you get NA values. If you list full.names = T, this solves the issue. As pointed by Spacedman.

```
file.info(list.files(path ="C:\\temp\\dat\\work", pattern =".T$", full.names = T))
```

Comment: @user5249203I tried this. It gave me the same result I mentioned in my question

Comment: Check the edits and see if you could solve the problem.

Comment: I tried doing this for another folder. It lists all the files but everything else is listed as NA recorder_type.xls                              NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
resource data types.xls                        NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>